# Send web push notifications to specific users through js in a php web app

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, web-push

is there any way out / resource which can guide how we can send the push notifications through a javascript to a specific user (through a device id). We have a web app that contains of a login functionality backed by MySQL. We want to send specific alerts to the specific users who are registered. We are open to take any more hidden detail of user if required to complete this task.

We are currently using the JS push notification library to send push notifications but thats currently static not dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You could run an ajax-call in the background which calls a script with the `user-id` as an parameter and that returns the messages you want to show to the specific user. Then you can show the message to the user.